# S3/CloudFront DNS host doesn't update only in Korea IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I used AWS S3/CloudFront to host my website: donghwankim.com

**donghwankim.com** is correctly updated in most IP.
But in Korean IP, **donghwankim.com** fail to update.

Why does AWS S3/CloudFront display older version only in Korean IP?
Thank you.

---

My website at Korean IP(vpn off) vs My website at American IP(vpn on)

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this issue resolved ? i can see mention is having certificate. @Bingkongmaster

Comment: Yes. I had to create invalidation in CloudFront to delete cache. @aviboy2006

Comment: add your answer and accept so that this question will answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the update failure was due to CloudFront caching my request.

I had to invalidate my cache at Cloudfront Distributions-ID-Invalidations-Create Invalidation by inputting `*`.